# window.addEventListener Stops working once iframe is loaded inside body

Tags: javascript, iframe

The below code works at start , but stops working once iframe is loaded inside body (iframe is loading scorm course), I looked for event.stopPropagation in all the files loaded by iframe but didn't find any.

I am not able to add any event. Also tried capture `true` option but didn't work.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        console.log(e.target)
        console.log('hi')
    })
```

I appending iframe from JavaScript after window is loaded

```
let iframeElement = document.createElement('iframe');
iframeElement.setAttribute("id", "socrmContent");
iframeElement.setAttribute("name", "socrmContent");
iframeElement.setAttribute("width", "100%");
iframeElement.setAttribute("height", "100%");
iframeElement.setAttribute("scrolling", "auto");
iframeElement.setAttribute("frameborder", "0");
iframeElement.setAttribute("src", "");
document.getElementById("iframe-container").appendChild(iframeElement);
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: so the event listener is adjacent to the iframe? (not inside?). My tests show it works fine

Comment: I have added image of the the structure, I tried everything it is not working

Comment: Where are your two codes in the file? I think whatever you have added works fine so problem might be somewhere else.

Comment: Both are in same file , iframe is created after window is loaded. I tried everything but is not working. It is a straight forward thing.

Comment: Yeah, I just made a quick snippet with your code and it worked, put a setTimeout on either listener or iframe, still worked fine

Comment: Can you share the snippet , I tried Not working

Comment: When I gave fixed width to iframe, i got the eventlistner to work outside that width but not working on iframe, i have added image of that

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the keyboard focus is in the iframe and not the main window.

Each iframe instance has its own window object and is accessible via `iframeElement.contentWindow`. In your case the following is what you want:

```
iframeElement.contentWindow.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    console.log(e.target)
    console.log('hi')
})
```

There is also a contentDocument so if you want to get an element inside an iframe you would use `iframeElement.contentDocument.getElementById("your-id");`

JSFiddle working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/7h0jfv3x/

If you click the red part you are running inside the iframe.

Press a key and you'll get console output.

Click outside the red part you are running outside the iframe.

Press a key and nothing happens.

Comment: I tried this before posting this and it did work. Does the console give any error and did you click inside the iframe before pressing the key?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome Version 91.0.4472.114 (Official Build) (64-bit), i tried on all the browsers but still not working

Comment: Added fiddle example to demonstrate it does work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234048/discussion-between-miran-parkar-and-john).